# Slider will be sent multiple values instead of the last value I want

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to use the Slider component in one project on react-native. The idea is someone can increase/decrease the number of participants for an event using a slider. I set up the component like this:

```
return (
    <View>
      <Text>{value} participants</Text>
      <Slider
        style={{ height: 40 }}
        minimumValue={eventDetail.minParticipants}
        maximumValue={eventDetail.maxParticipants + 10}
        minimumTrackTintColor='#000000'
        maximumTrackTintColor='#FF0000'
        step={1}
        onValueChange={value => setMaxParticipantsHandler(value)}
      />
    </View>
  );
```

Once a value changes in the sliders, the function executes sending the new value.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(eventDetail.maxParticipants);

  const setMaxParticipantsHandler = value => {
    setValue(value);
    console.log('reading: ' + value);
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('sending: ' + value);
    }, 5000);
  };
```

But when I test this, the setTimeout() executes multiple times. The console log throws this:

```
reading: 9
sending: 9
reading: 8
reading: 7
reading: 6
reading: 5
reading: 4
reading: 4
sending: 8
sending: 7
sending: 6
sending: 5
sending: 4
sending: 4
```

I want to delay the execution and dispatch only one value to the API (the last one instead of several); I'm figuring out if I need to do this here on the screen or do the logic on the redux-store, like first to save the value on the state, and if it is the same, I don't ask the API, but if the value of the state is different I do send an API request.

Comment: remember what you sent the last time and trigger a communication only if the current value differs

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. The Slider component already has a prop that only triggers the callback when you're done sliding: onSlidingComplete. The prop I was using is good for other user cases, like updating the counter.